# Getting rows from a table by index in special cases using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, html-table, webdriver

We have a table where the first row in the *tbody* actually describes the headers rather than the headers being in a *thead*. So I have something like the following to get the headers.

```
 @FindBy(xpath = "//table/tbody/tr[1]/th")
 private List<WebElement> headerRows.
```

I would like to make something similar to get the detail rows (starting from row 2).  If I do

```
 @FindBy(xpath = "//table/tbody/tr")
 private List<WebElement> detailRows;
```

This will also get the header row.  I would like to exclude index 1.  I tried this:

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//table/tbody/tr[!1]") and @FindBy(xpath="//table/tbody/tr[not(1)]")
```

but those didn't work?  Any suggestions?  I can do it with code and find and skip the first row when reading in a loop if necessary:

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//table/tbody/tr")
 private WebElement rows;

 for (int i = 1; i rows.size(); i++) {
      WebElement row = rows.get(i);
 }
```

but that does not seem elegant.  Is that the best way?

Comment: you should be able to construct a locator that describes all rows that contain children of td...  (sibling) ultimately the locator will depend on what you are doing with those webelements.  Are you getting the cells for each row?  Only a certain cell in each?  You can probably construct a locator to get at just what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude `header row` you can use below xpath, which will ignore `th` column.

```
//table/tbody/tr[not(th)]
```

your code will be

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//table/tbody/tr[not(th)]")
 private List<WebElement> detailRows;
```

Comment: let me check that

Comment: Let me know how this goes?